# GUI extension weird issue after upgrading to Web 8.5

Tags: cme, gui-extensions, web8.5

I am facing a weird issue after upgrading one of my GUI extensions (to add a new button in the ribbon tool bar and to work upon any component) from Tridion 2013 to SDL Web 8.5. Once I deployed, it was working fine. But when, after some time, I restarted the app pool and services, the GUI extension stopped working: components never load and the wheel spins forever. I can’t see any JS error in browser console. I am wondering if there is any trick to fix this issue.

While debugging, when I browsed `http://example.com/WebUI/Editors/CME/Views/Component/Component.aspx?mode=js`, it shows me this error:

> System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.Exception:
>   The reference to configuration group "" cannot be resolved. at
>   Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedJsGroup.ResolveResources(Dictionary`2
>   resources) at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedJsGroup.get_Resources() at
>   Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedJsGroup.GetLastModifiedTime(CachedResourceType
>   resourceType, List`1 checkedResources) at
>   Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedJsGroup.GetLastModifiedTime(List`1
>   checkedResources) at
>   Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedJsGroup.GetLastModifiedTime(CachedResourceType
>   resourceType, List`1 checkedResources) at
>   Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedJsGroup.GetLastModifiedTime(List`1
>   checkedResources) at
>   Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedJsGroup.GetLastModifiedTime(CachedResourceType
>   resourceType, List`1 checkedResources) at
>   Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedJsGroup.GetLastModifiedTime(List`1
>   checkedResources) at
>   Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedJsControlResources.GetLastModifiedTime(CachedResourceType
>   resourceType, List`1 checkedResources) at
>   Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedJsControlResources.GetLastModifiedTime(CachedResourceType
>   resourceType) at
>   Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedJsControlResources.GetLastModifiedTime() at
>   Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Common.HttpUtilities.OutputWithHTTPCacheHeaders(ICachedResource
>   resource, CachedResourceType resourceType, Nullable`1 cacheDuration)
>   at Tridion.Web.UI.Controls.TridionPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e) at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Answer (score 3):

After seeing the error message, I have added bolow lines in the \web\WebUI\WebRoot\Configuration\System.config:

```
<group name="">
</group>
```

This trick worked as a fix for my GUI extension issue also. I can't see if this trick is mentioned in SDL documentation. Before, accepting it as an answer, I will wait for some formal/documented answer to fix this issue.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that you got an empty `<cfg:dependency/>` tag somewhere in your extension configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Some of the Core control namespaces has got changed between Tridion 2013 and SDL Web 8.5. So, You would also need to upgrade your UI Extension by recompiling against the SDL Web 8.5 reference assemblies to resolve the issue.